# How do I make a complex UI layout with html/css grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, design-patterns, format

I'm trying to make this complex layout shown below:
[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: posts; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'header header header header header header'
  'main main main main main main'
  'menu posts posts posts posts posts';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Navbar</div>
  <div class="item2">Small Picture</div>
  <div class="item3">Big Picture</div>  
  <div class="item4">Posts</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm not even close. I'm not sure How I would get the small picture tab (shown in the picture) to be over the Tab Menu and the Big picture in my original layout design. Is this possible with CSS grid? If so, how would I do it?

If it's not possible or too difficult with CSS, what would you recommend I do instead?

Comment: That is not complex UI layout . Just use position (e.g. relative / absolute) and z-index to set in your CSS

Comment: @KenLee ooh, you mean like position: absolute for the sidebar or something and then just manually do it like top: 100px; or something? that makes sense. Tho I wasn't sure if that's the best way to approach it

Comment: To use a CSS grid, the first step is to extend the lines of each main box vertically and horizontally to the edges of the layout, that will give you the grid you need. Then you need to let various items extend beyond just a single cell.  I'd probably implement the small picture / details part with a separate, absolutely positioned element though,

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the tips, I was considering it tho I wasn't sure if it was the best approach to use.

Comment: Here's one approach: https://jsfiddle.net/rv7ec20h/

Comment: @ChrisG awesome, thanks! I really appreciate it. you should post that as answer so I can accept you.

Comment: Improved version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wmqfs51r/